# How to read array document field from firebase firestore (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am trying to get todo array field from cloud firestore database in a react project. When i print out with console log I can see the empty array symbol but It throws error at the same time and does not render the page.

[image]

This is the Firestore.js file to get data from firebase.

```
export const userTodoList = async (email) => {
  await onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", email), (doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data().todos);
    return doc.data().todos;
  });
};
```

This the MainPage.js file to get the array and pass to CardList component.

```
 const MainPage = () => {
      const todoArray = userTodoList(auth.currentUser.email);
      const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todoArray);
      return (
        <div>
          <section>
            <NavBar></NavBar>
            <ToDoForm />
          </section>
          <section>
            <CardList array={todos} />
          </section>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

This is the CardList component to render the cards with the array mapping. I am checking for if the array length is 0 or not but still get errors.

```
const CardList = (props) => {
  const array = props.array;
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div className="grid_container">
        <h2>Found no todos</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="grid_container">
      {array.map((todo) => (
        <Card title={todo.title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Errors.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **object.map is not a function** error occurs because the map method is not implemented on objects. To iterate over an object, use the `Object.keys()` method to get an array of the object's keys and call the `map()`method on the array of keys.

I.e You can use `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` and then use `map`

For example:

```
array.keys(obj).map(key => {
  //other statements
});
```

For more details you can check this [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-object-map-is-not-a-function#:%7E:text=map%20is%20not%20a%20function%22%20error%20occurs%20because%20the%20map,on%20the%20array%20of%20keys.)

Comment: Thank you so much I am a beginner at react js and did not realize the return value is an object not an array. Also I forgot to use useEffect hook to get data correctly I combined your answer with hook my problem is solved thank you